# JS Function doubles

Tags: javascript

I should find the factorial of a number written in input. I have the function but the problem is that how many time I press on button it will *2 the number. I am not able to empty the value of the input and .

Here is the code.

Thank you in advance!

```css
let sum = 1; 
function faktorial(){
    let faktorial1 = +inp1.value
    for(let i = 1; i < faktorial1; i++){
        sum *=i+1
    }
    tpel.innerHTML =  sum
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" name="" id="inp1">
    <!-- <input type="text" name="" id="inp2"> -->
    <br>
    <!-- <button onclick="show()">Print</button> -->
    <button onclick="faktorial()">Faktorial</button>
    <h1 id="tpel"></h1>

</body>
<script src="script.js"></script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `sum` again to 1 and also if you need to remove the input value, you need to set `inp1.value` to `""`. Check the code below.

```js
let sum = 1; 
function faktorial(){
    let faktorial1 = +inp1.value
    for(let i = 1; i < faktorial1; i++){
        sum *=i+1
    }
    tpel.innerHTML =  sum
    sum = 1;
    inp1.value = "";
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" name="" id="inp1">
    <!-- <input type="text" name="" id="inp2"> -->
    <br>
    <!-- <button onclick="show()">Print</button> -->
    <button onclick="faktorial()">Faktorial</button>
    <h1 id="tpel"></h1>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function faktorial(){
    let sum = 1; 
    let faktorial1 = +inp1.value
    for(let i = 1; i < faktorial1; i++){
        sum *=i+1
    }
    
    tpel.innerHTML =  sum
    sum = null;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" name="" id="inp1">
    <!-- <input type="text" name="" id="inp2"> -->
    <br>
    <!-- <button onclick="show()">Print</button> -->
    <button onclick="faktorial()">Faktorial</button>
    <h1 id="tpel"></h1>

</body>
<script src="script.js"></script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Calculating factorial of a number is typical use-case of recursive function

```js
function faktorial1() {
  tpel.innerText = faktorial(inp1.value);
}

function faktorial(x) {
  if (x == 0) {
    return 1;
  }
  return x * faktorial(x - 1);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="" id="inp1">
<button onclick="faktorial1()">Faktorial</button>
<h1 id="tpel"></h1>
```